# How to go on from here (Thevenin circuit)?

Tags: thevenin, norton

[image: What I've got so far]

[image: Question]

Basically, I've discovered the "total" resistance, being 6/11 Ohms. Same resistance would be found in Norton's circuit.

Now, I know that the sum of all voltages should be zero. I was thinking to go with 2.2-1*I+11-1.2*I=0 and get I=6A (1.2 is the total resistance of the resistors of 2Ohm and 3 Ohm which are in parallel). But if I do get I to be 6 A I can't find Vth to be 10.2V. 
Could you help me?

PS: This is NOT Homework

Comment: You're applying KVL wrong because 2- and 3-ohm resistors are not simply in parallel but separated by a voltage source.

Comment: Hint: the easiest way to solve this problem is to apply the method of [source transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_transformation).

Comment: How would you get rid of the 2- and 3-ohm resistors?

Comment: apply source transformation to your voltage sources which will change them to current sources.

Comment: I=V/R
Do I sum the voltages (11+2.2) and divide by the total resistance (6/11)? Or do I divide 2.2 by 6/11 and then 11 by 6/11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2.2V & 1-ohm source is equivalent to a 2.2A source and 1-ohm. Then this resistor is in parallel with the 2ohm one, so it becomes a 2/3 ohm resistor.

Then transform it back to voltage source of 4.4/3 V (and 2/3 ohm resistor).

To calculate the Norton current the output is shorted so the 3-ohm resistor goes away.

Then you add the voltage sources as 11+(4.4/3) = 37.4/3 V. And this divided by 2/3 ohms gives exactly 18.7A Norton current.

---

If the direct calculation of the Norton current confuses you, and for verification purposes, we can also calculate the Thévenin voltage basically using the same approach [of source transformations].

We can reuse our previous transformation of the left-most voltage source and of the two resistors next to it into a 4.4/3 V source with a [series] 2/3 ohm resistor.

But after that, for the Thévenin voltage the output is left open-circuit. So now we do have that 3 ohm resistor in the circuit, and we need to calculate the voltage drop across it, which will be the Thévenin voltage we're looking for.

Now the 4.4/3 V source in series the 11V one is again 37.4/3 V, but this voltage goes through a voltage divider formed by a 2/3 ohm and a 3ohm resistor, and we want to find the voltage drop across the latter:

$$ V_{th} = \frac{37.4}{3}V\times \frac{3}{3+\frac{2}{3}} =  37.4V\times \frac {3}{11} = \frac{112.2}{11}V = 10.2V$$

As you probably know, the Thévenin voltage is related to the Norton current by the Thévenin/Norton resistance (which you have correctly found as 6/11 ohms): \$10.2V = 18.7A \times \frac{6}{11}\Omega\$.

---

The last part of your problem, calculating the current through the 16/11 ohm load is much more trivial, e.g. using the Thévenin source we have 10.2V going through (6+16)/11 ohms, i.e. trough 2 ohms, so the load current is 5.1A.

With that load added, a Norton source of 18.7A sees a resistance of (6/11)||(16/11) ohms. Furthermore, this is a current divisor, i.e. we want to know the current [only] through the 16/11 ohms load. The current through the load is thus

$$ 18.7A \times \frac{\frac{11}{16}}{\frac{11}{6} + \frac{11}{16}} = 18.7A \times \frac{3}{11} = 5.1A$$

So, it's the same load current as we got with the Thévenin source, as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Just a few questions:
Why does the 3-ohm resistor goes away? When should I ignore other resistors/voltage/current sources?

Comment: Because it's in parallel with a zero-ohm resistor when you short the output, which is what you do when you calculate the Norton current.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "it's in parallel with a zero-ohm resistor"? Where did it come from?
Also, why did you consider the 2-ohm resistor to be in series with the 1-ohm? Whenever you have two voltage sources you just consider two circuits separately?

Once again, thank you

Comment: I think you need to watch some lecture on these to understand what I did and why did it. I suggest these two: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyPMMtW-2dc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-3NWNrAQRQ

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I'm going to watch the videos and if I still get confused with something I'll let you know. Again, thank you :)

Comment: Hi again! I've watched the videos and I think I've understood it! Thank you! I'll do the same exercise again tomorrow and I'll look for others online. @Respawned I would only like to ask you if I got this general formula right.
When I need to calculate a Voltage across a resistor, I do V=V0*(R0/RT), being V0 the Voltage Source, R0 the resistor I'm considering and RT the total resistance (if in Series, R0+R1+R2... if in Parallel, 1/R0+1/R1+1/R2, etc). If I'm considering a current, same thing, but I0 instead of I and I get the current across the resistor. Correct?

Comment: @Alex Couto: Yes, for a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) the voltage drop across each resistor is proportional to the resistance (of that resistor). For a [current divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider), the current through each resistor [is proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider#Using_Admittance) with the [conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) of the resistor (i.e. the inverse of the resistance). That's what I did in the last calculation.

Comment: Ok, thank you! You were really helpful, @RespawnedFluff!

Comment: @Alex Couto: For just two resistors, it's actually possible to [have simpler formula for the current divider](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94888/current-divider-rule-calculation-issue/198235#198235), but I'm a bit rusty.